# Problem with creating a div into the document (DOM)

Tags: vue.js

I have some problems with this fragment, it creates a div into the DOM so that div appears in every page as it is normal, which is an image.

How can I change it so this div is only being created when I access at this custom component (Model.vue) and no longer being visible once I'm out of the component page.

Thanks!!

```
container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
```

Comment: Don't modify the DOM this way if you're using Vue.js. Instead, look up how to dynamically create elements 'the vue way'.

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is predictable you should probably add it in your template (as HTML or as a component) and then show/hide it with `v-if` or `v-show`

If you need static content, for example depending on the user input, then [`v-html` is the way](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Interpretation-du-HTML).

If you need dynamic content (e.g. with event bindings), then check out [render functions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html).

There's also [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) like `<component :is="someComponent">`, where `someComponent` can be either a string name of the component, or the component itself. But you should probably try the other solution first.

Answer (score -1):

First of all direct DOM manipulation(Add/Del elements) is not at all preferred in vuejs. You can use v-if instead to show the element conditionally.

Or else if you still want to do direct manipulation then you can write the above lines of code in mounted hook of your model.vue component.

```
mounted() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  container.setAttribute("id", "divId");
}
```

And then in before destroyed hook you can remove this element from the DOM as below.

```
beforeDestroy() {
  var elem = document.querySelector('#divId');
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's working fine but for some reason once I enter another page I can't type text anymore

Comment: "First of all direct DOM manipulation(Add/Del elements) is not at all preferred in vuejs." Imo you shouldn't provide this answer. OP has a wrong approach. That doesn't mean your answer should build on the same wrong approach. It promotes wrong practice.